# Seleccione una pestaña específica en Materilize usando Jquery

Tags: jquery, materialize

Quiero seleccionar una pestaña a través de jquery y estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
 $ (". tabs"). tabs ("select", "#tabId");
```

Pero no me funciona.

En la documentación de material aparece lo siguiente:

```
$ ('. tabs'). tabs ('methodName', paramName);
```

Estoy utilizando material [v1.0.0](https://materializecss.com/)

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Te da algún error? De ser así por favor pongo el la pregunta. Sería recomendable que realices un ejemplo verificable de tu error en un snippet/fiddle/pen para que podamos ayudarte.